# how to optimize this traditional "for" loop for this case?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm playing with an Angular app, I have a method in a service that raises an `HTTP get` request to JSONplaceholder, and the response is an object array with 100 posts. I was wondering how can I render only 10 out of those 100 posts, and only could think about creating an auxiliary variable and do the following:

```
  posts:any;
  
  modified:any[] = [];
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe( res =>
      {
        this.posts = res;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.posts.length; i++) {          
          i < 10 ? this.modified.push(this.posts[i]) : void(0);          
        }
      } 
    )
  }
```

This works, but I have to iterate the `modified` variable in my template, and I'm pretty sure there are better ways to improve this, with a better approach. How can this little code be a little better?

Thanks

Comment: [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) does exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array.slice - the function takes two parameters, 'start' and 'end'.

'end' signifies the index after the last item that you want (it is not inclusive of the 'end' index), and is optional. If 'end' is not supplied, you will get all elements starting at end and continuing to the end of the array.

So, in your case,

```
modified = posts.slice(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

just concerning the for loop you can do

```
for ( let i=0, len=this.posts.length; i<len; i++ ){
  // code
}
```

this way you will only run `this.posts.length` once (this is just in case `ths.posts` has lots of data)

Answer (score 0):

To handle arrays you can always check the JavaScript Array docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

In this case you could use the `slice` method:

`this.modified = res.slice(0,10);`